# Spring cloud vs. Spring platform BOMs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have some questions related to dependency management with spring "Bill of materials":

- Should I use both for a complete spring dependency management?
- Are they incompatible? Any problems?

Our project uses several dependencies that are managed by platform BOM

Comment: There is a conversation about this at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-starters/issues/49

Comment: You can use both, but the cloud BOM needs to override the platform BOM because it has newer dependencies. I'll post the example from the docs in a bit.

Comment: @spencergibb thanks for your comment and the commit in starters docs. IMHO spring platform BOM should manage those dependencies or it is going to give us a headache updating packages. We are going to match both BOMs by spring-boot version, do you recommend any other approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-starters/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-starters.adoc#using-spring-cloud-dependencies-with-spring-io-platform)

> The Spring Cloud Dependencies BOM must go first, so that its
>   dependencies have precedence of the Spring IO Platform dependencies.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.SR1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

It [was determined](https://github.com/spring-io/platform/issues/232) that the platform can not manage spring cloud's dependencies. This is the recommended way to use the spring platform with spring cloud.